# What's the SEO impact of using a shared CDN URL

Tags: seo, cdn, magento, geolocation

Say I have a Magento webshop with 4 different store-fronts and a European CDN which has a customized DNS lookup handler which localizes your CDN DNS lookups (so looking up `cdn.myshop.co.uk` from France gives you a local french CDN server IP):

- `myshop.co.uk`
- `mijnwinkel.nl`
- `meingeschaft.de`
- `monmagasin.fr`

Can I set the CDN to `cdn.myshop.co.uk` and use that for `image/skin/js` hosting for all the other domains (as long as I accept cross-domain scripting from those domains) or would it be better to create a cdn. sub domain for each domain I have?

So, rephrased: Would the site 'mijnwinkel.nl' rank lower if it uses `cdn.myshop.co.uk` instead of `cdn.mijnwinkel.nl` ... or are we talking purely cosmetics here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google and other search engines generally value content where they are embedded and not where they are physically hosted. It's common for companies and bloggers to use content delivery networks without using their domain name i.e Amazon.com, Rackspace.co.uk and so forth. Unless you care about branding which in your examples you do not you shouldn't need to use a custom domain.

It should be noted that when using a custom domain with a CDN service you actually create an additional lookup which adds a delay to rendering, however it is minor but thought I'd let you know.

Comment: Thank you.. it's what I thought myself, but I was looking for confirmation from a peer... do you by any chance have a source to this information?